# Asset.css in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, mootools

My application uses a Mootools class Asset to include CSS and JS files at run time. The line below used to include a CSS file:

```
var myStyleSheet = Asset.css('/styles/myStyle.css');
```

I need to change this line to jQuery since the rest of the script is already in jQuery. How can we do that in jQuery?

Comment: I am sure you confused Asset.css with Asset.javascript :)

Comment: yeah... totally.. thanks for edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple way to do it in plain javascript.. Just try the below lines and voila !!

```
var cssfile=document.createElement("link") ;
cssfile.setAttribute("rel", "stylesheet");
cssfile.setAttribute("type", "text/css");
cssfile.setAttribute("href", "/styles/myStyle.css");

if (typeof cssfile!="undefined") {
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(cssfile) ;
}
```