# Get url from google chrome tab

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I'm building an extension for chrome, and I'm trying to pass the chrome tab url (with JS) dynamically to the html file. I read other people questions regarding the same issue, but it didn't work in my case.

My knowledge of JS and HTML is basic, but I don't know how to move the parameter data between them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, set the permissions for the tab API :

```
"permissions": [
    "tabs"
]
```

And then store the URL :

```
chrome.tabs.getSelected(null,function(tab) {
    var tablink = tab.url;
});
```

Or another way: (preferred)

```
chrome.tabs.query({'active': true}, function (tabs) {
    var url = tabs[0].url;
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer!, but how I move the "url" var to a <p></p> paragraph tab in the html file?

Comment: I didn't get your query. But maybe you can try document.write() to make the element. OR try to create a new element using something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14473120/asset-css-in-jquery/14473198#14473198

Comment: I went over the DOM documentation (all the "getElementsBy.." stuff ), and I found the answer, thanks man! you are the best!